# Parameters with ASP.NET MVC routes for same number of params

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Route matching requires the parameter name to match. So the below will match any action with a single parameter fileid. However, it does *not* match any action with a single parameter of a different name. Therefore, I have another route for actions that take a single parameter sessionid.

The second route doesn't work, only the first one declared. This confuses me: I understand that matching stops with the first match found, but if it doesn't match the first parameter name then surely a match has *not* been found and matching should continue? But it doesn't.

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DownloadUrl",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{fileid}"
    );
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Queue",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{sessionid}"
    );
```

I could use a single route and call my parameters A, B, C... essentially naming them for ordinal position.

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DownloadUrl",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{A}"
    );
```

But that's horrible code so I assume I do not understand routing well enough. How do I express both these routes?

Comment: Why is it important to you what's the name of the parameter? The default route in any mvc project is api/{controller}/{action}/{id}. Why do you care what the parameter is called? All you need to know is that you can pass some value in. From that point of view these two routes are identical...

Comment: I like my code to be self-documenting. And if it were intended to be used like that, what is the point of insisting that the route parameter token name match the function parameter name?

Answer (score 0):

Experimentation has revealed that explicit naming combined with defaults can sort this out:

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Authenticate",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/Authenticate/{email}/{password}",
    defaults: new { action = "Authenticate" }
  );
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "UploadedBytes",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/UploadedBytes/{sessiondId}/{fileid}",
    defaults: new { action = "UploadedBytes" }
    );
```

Comment: If you are defining a default action as you do here you can safely make your route be: api/{controller}/{action}/{email}/{password}. But yes if you want to pass in multiple parameters you define a route that takes two parameters. What they are called is irrelevant.